# Most recent instance between dates

Tags: sql, date

What I currently have...

[image]

What my goal dataset should look like...

[image]

As you can see, I need a new column that takes the rows where Type = "Repair" and places the date of the most recent date where Type = "PM".  Example above shows repairs 11/19 & 10/26 so I would need the 9/29 Date since it's the most recent PM date.  For repairs dated 9/8, 8/21 & 8/5 I would need the 7/26 PM date since it's the most recent PM date before those repairs.  This would be the pattern for many months of data.  Thanks!

*****After adding the recommended Windows function this is what I get*****

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       (case when type <> 'PM'
             then max(case when type = 'PM' then date end) over (partition by id order by date)
        end) as most_recent_pm_date
from t
```

This assumes that you want the most recent date per `id`.

Comment: Getting much closer.  When I add that windows function, it's correct for some of the rows.

Comment: I added a screenshot to the original post of what I'm seeing when I add the function.Thanks!

Comment: @JBrewer . . . Needs an `order by date`.

Comment: So apparently we're running a really, really old SQL server version...2005!  When I add the order by in the statement it's giving me an error which led me to research and find out just how old our version is.  Any trick to getting this to work on 2005?

Comment: @JBrewer . . . I would suggest you upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server.  SQL Server 2005 has been out of even extended support for years, so running it is simply dangerous, because security holes are not fixed.